# Error loading Libraries: error while loading shared libraries: lib***: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libraries, hpc

Trying to run a program on an HPC and am getting an error loading shared libraries for multiple libraries. It was initially on hdf5 library so in the make file I added a line

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/work/uij207/hdf5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and am now getting the same error for libgsl. My Makefile is:

```
ifeq ($(SYSTYPE),"ARC")
CC       =  mpicc
CXX      =  mpic++
FC       =  $(CC)
OPTIMIZE = -O2  -funroll-loops
OPTIMIZE += -g -Wall # compiler warnings
#OPTIMIZE += -parallel -openmp  # openmp (comment out this line if OPENMP not used)
ifeq (OPENMP,$(findstring OPENMP,$(CONFIGVARS)))
OPTIMIZE += -parallel -openmp  # openmp required compiler flags
endif
GMP_INCL = #
GMP_LIBS = #
MKL_INCL = #
MKL_LIBS = #
##MKL_LIBS = -L$(TACC_MKL_LIB) -lm -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64
GSL_INCL = -I/work/uij207/gizmo-public/libraries/gsl/include
GSL_LIBS = -L/work/uij207/gizmo-public/libraries/gsl/lib
FFTW_INCL= -I/work/uij207/gizmo-public/libraries/fftw/include
FFTW_LIBS= -L/work/uij207/gizmo-public/libraries/fftw/lib
HDF5INCL = -I/work/uij207/hdf5/include -DH5_USE_16_API
HDF5LIB  = -L/work/uij207/hdf5/lib -lhdf5 -lz
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/work/uij207/hdf5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
MPICHLIB = #
OPT     += -DUSE_MPI_IN_PLACE
## modules to load:
## module load intel mvapich2 gsl hdf5 fftw2
##  -- performance is very similar with impi (intel-mpi) instead of mpavich2,
##   if preferred use that with MPICHLIB line uncommented
## newest version of code needed for compatibility with calls in MPI-2 libraries
##
endif
```

and the slurm file is

```
#!/bin/bash
#----------------------------------------------------
# Sample Slurm job script for Arc nodes
#SBATCH -J GIZMOTEST1 # Job Name
#SBATCH -o Test1.o%j # Name of the stdout output file
#SBATCH -e Test1.e%j # Name of stderr error file
#SBATCH -p compute1 # Queue (partition) name
#SBATCH -N 1 # Total # of nodes (must be 1 for serial)
#SBATCH -n 1 # Total # of mpi tasks (should be 1 for serial)
#SBATCH -t 01:30:00 # Run time (hh:mm:ss)
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=dale.bobar@utsa.edu
#Put other commands such as module load if needed after this line (All commands must follow #SBATCH directives)
module purge
module load gnu8 mpich/3.3.1 fftw gsl
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/hdf5/lib
# Launch code...
./gizmo-public/GIZMO ./gizmo-public/isodisktest/isodisk.params.txt 0
```

when I run sbatch it submits the job and immediately fails where the error file states "error while loading shared libraries: lib***: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Do I need to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH for each library?

Comment: "Do I need to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH for each library?"

Yes, you need the locations of all the libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime unless they have been encoded in the binary RUNPATH or RPATH. You could put all the library files in a single directory or symlink to them from a single directory if you do not want to add multiple paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH